# How to close jquery popup after SERVER validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am making a web site using ASP.net, and i would like to make a nice login popup with JQuery ModalDialog (Or ajax...i don't know much about ajax). I have a database containing every allowed users, and I would like to close the popup if the user successfully logged in (If not, i want the popup to stay, and display an error message). The problem is that My validation is done serverside, and JQuery runs on the client side.

Comment: Could you provide some code mate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way is to make a jQuery ajax call from inside your dialog , then a webmethod in code behind that listens to this ajax , the webmethod will return successful login , or unsuccessful and you handle removing the dialog client side

i'll get some example code for you

```
        function fnValidateLogIn() {         
        $('#<%= lblLoginMessage.ClientID %>').text("");
        var email = $('#<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>').val();
        var pass = $('#<%= txtPass.ClientID %>').val();
        if (pass == "") {
            $('#<%= lblLoginMessage.ClientID %>').text("Please Enter A Password");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Login.aspx/LoginUser",
                data: "{'email':'" + email + "', 'pass' : '" + pass + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
                    if (obj.login == "failed") $('#<%= lblLoginMessage.ClientID %>').text("Login Failed");
                    if (obj.login == "success") {
                        location.reload(true);   //you can hide popup instead of refreshing
                        window.location = $('.hidden_url').text();  //you can hid popup instead of redirect 
                    }
                }
           });
            return false;
        }
    }
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
       <System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
       Public Shared Function LoginUser(email As String, pass As String) As String

        'code to validate user

       return "{ ""login "" : ""success"" }"  'example
```

THat is in VB.Net , but you can get the idea

Comment: I edited the code , I chose to refresh in my code , but that is where you would handle the popup you want to hide , also send the response back as json - just a string will work for only one parameter ,

Answer (score 0):

This depends which jquery plugin you are using for the pop up.

Basically You need to get the handle of the pop up. The plugin should have a close function and you need to call it after you get the successful response from your server. Most of he plugins usually have something like `$("#pop_up_id").close();`

Answer (score 0):

on server side make one web method which return a string

```
If successful login it will return 'success'
or if invalid login it willl return 'fail'
```

Now on client side use jQuery ajax function make ajax call to your method like this

```
$.ajax(
url:your.asmx/webmethod
data:{username:$('#usernametextboxid').val(),password:$('#passwordtextbox').val()
type:'POST'
dataType:'json'
success:function(data){
//logic to hide popup

if(data.d=='success'){$('#modalpopupid').close()}
else if(data.d=='fail'){$('#modalpopupid').html('Invalid login')}
else{alert('some error occured.Please try again')}

}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scott Selby, in your code, you are refreshing the page, which is killing the meaning of ajax. The modal window can be closed just by calling the close() function of the plugin without a page refresh.

Comment: in my code , I chose to redirect to another page , but that is where you would hide the dialog